# Object is empty randomly after fetch without issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, react-context

I'm solving bugs on a website with maps API. I noticed that sometimes the markers wouldn't render, even though my fetch of info to the backend served the info.
I have now noticed that the object that carries the info to the markers function is sometimes empty and I can't understand why.
I'm new to react and didn't do the majority of the coding behind.

TestMap.tsx

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import React, { useState, useEffect, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { useGeoReportState } from '../../context/GeoReportContext';
import { useMapContext } from '../../context/MapContext';
import { findMode, formSubmitGeoCoder, getSoilTypeColor } from '../../utils/Util';
import Navbar from '../Navbar';
import { notificationHandler, surveyLengthHandler } from '../../utils/ContextHandlers';
import { MarkerClusterer, SuperClusterAlgorithm } from '@googlemaps/markerclusterer';
import Icon from '../../img/point.png';
import FileSubmit from '../Form/FileSubmit';
import Form from '../Form/Form';
import ThankYou from '../Form/ThankYou';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { AiOutlineLeft, AiOutlineRight, AiOutlineReload } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { GeoReport, Survey } from '../../types/GeoReportTypes';
import { SurveyData } from '../../types/SurveyTypes';
import { useNotificationDispatch } from '../../context/NotificationContext';
import { useSurveyDispatch } from '../../context/SurveyContext';
import PointData from '../Form/PointData';
import { useGoogleMap } from '@ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks';

const TestMap: React.FC = () => {
    const geoReportState = useGeoReportState();
    const notificationDispatch = useNotificationDispatch();
    const mapState = useMapContext();
    const surveyDispatch = useSurveyDispatch();
    const map = useGoogleMap();

    let formData = {};

    const [showFileSubmit, setShowFileSubmit] = useState(false);
    const [showSliderForms, showSlider] = useState(false);
    const [showThankYouForms, setShowThankYou] = useState(false);
    const [surveys, setSurveys] = useState<Survey[]>([]);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();
    const [thisMarkers, setThisMarkers] = useState<google.maps.Marker[]>([]);
    const [circles, setCircles] = useState<google.maps.Circle[]>([]);
    const [pointDataArray, setPointDataArray] = useState<GeoReport | null>(null);
    const [distanceBetween, setDistanceBetween] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [surveyNumber, setSurveyNumber] = useState(surveys.length + 1);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] =useState<string>();

    const incrementCount = () => {
        setSurveyNumber(surveyNumber + 1);
    };

    const resetCount = () => {
        setSurveyNumber(1);
    };

    //const [imgData, setImgData] = useState<any[]>([]);
    //const fetchImages = async () => {
    //  await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/driveimage/getimg')
    //      .then(r => r.json())
    //      .then((data) => {
    //          data.forEach((img: any) => {
    //              imgData.push(img);
    //          });
    //          setImgData(imgData);
    //      });
    //};

    //useEffect(() => { fetchImages(); }, []);

    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => setIsMounted(true), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) return;
        if (isMounted && thisMarkers.length == 0) {
            console.log('hi useEffect');
            console.log(geoReportState);
            Object.entries(geoReportState.map).map(([, reports]) => {
                addMarkers(undefined, reports, thisMarkers, setThisMarkers, setPointDataArray);
                addCircles(undefined, setPointDataArray, reports, circles, setCircles);
            });
        }
        //console.log(thisMarkers);
        thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
            marker.setMap(map);
        });
    }, [mapState]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) return;

        map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
            if (map.getZoom()! >= 11) {
                thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                });
                circles.forEach(circle => {
                    circle.setMap(map);
                });
            }
            if (map.getZoom()! < 11) {
                thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
                    marker.setMap(map);
                });
                circles.forEach(circle => {
                    circle.setMap(null);
                });
            }
        });

    }, [map?.getZoom()]);

    thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
        marker.addListener('click', () => {
            if (showSliderForms === true) {
                showSlider(false);
            }
        });
    });

    const handleOpenSlider = () => {
        showSlider(!showSliderForms);
        if (pointDataArray) {
            handleClosePointData();
        }
    };

    const handleOpenFileSubmit = () => {
        if (surveys.length === 0) {
            notificationHandler(2, 'Por favor introduza valores válidos', notificationDispatch);
        } else {
            setShowFileSubmit(!showFileSubmit);
        };
    };

    const handleOpenThankYou = () => {
        setShowThankYou(!showThankYouForms);
    };

    const handleClosePointData = () => {
        setPointDataArray(null);
        setDistanceBetween(null);
    };

    const handleSubmitNew = () => {
        setShowThankYou(!showThankYouForms);
        setShowFileSubmit(!showFileSubmit);
        setSurveys([]);
        resetCount();
        setSelectedFile(null);
        setSelectedImage('');
    };

    const handleExit = () => {
        setShowThankYou(!showThankYouForms);
        setShowFileSubmit(!showFileSubmit);
        showSlider(!showSliderForms);
        setSurveys([]);
        resetCount();
        setSelectedFile(null);
        setSelectedImage('');
    };

    const handleAddSurvey = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; }, lat: number, lng: number, nFreatico: boolean, inFreatico: number, nSPT: boolean, table: SurveyData[]) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (lat === 0 || lng === 0 || lat === undefined || lng === undefined || table.length === 0 || (nFreatico === true && (inFreatico === undefined || inFreatico === 0))) {
            notificationHandler(2, 'Por favor introduza valores válidos', notificationDispatch);
        } else {
            if(nSPT) {
                table.map(e => e.spt1 = 1000);
            }
            if (nFreatico === true) {
                const dummy = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng,
                    nFreatico: nFreatico,
                    inFreatico: inFreatico,
                    table: table,
                };
                surveys.push(dummy);
            } else {
                const dummy = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng,
                    nFreatico: nFreatico,
                    inFreatico: 0,
                    table: table,
                };
                surveys.push(dummy);
            };
            setSurveys([...surveys]);
            incrementCount();
            notificationHandler(1, 'Sondagem submetida com sucesso', notificationDispatch);
            surveyLengthHandler(surveys.length, surveyDispatch);
        }
    };

    const handleClearSurveys = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setSurveys([]);
        resetCount();
    };

    const handleFileInput = (e: any, type: number) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (type === 1) {
            if (file) {
                if (file.type === 'application/pdf') {
                    setSelectedFile(file);
                } else {
                    notificationHandler(
                        2,
                        'Por favor seleciona um ficheiro tipo PDF',
                        notificationDispatch,
                    );
                }
            }
        } else if (selectedImage) {
            setSelectedImage(file);
        } 
        // else {
        //  notificationHandler(
        //      2,
        //      'Por favor seleciona uma imagem do tipo PNG ou JPEG',
        //      notificationDispatch
        //  );
        //}
    };

    const handleUploadPDF = (e: any, filename: string) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (selectedFile) {
            const formPDFData = new FormData();
            formPDFData.append('filename', filename);
            formPDFData.append('file', selectedFile);
            fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/drive', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formPDFData
            });
                //.then((response) => (console.log(response)))
                //.catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    };

    const handleUploadImage = (e: any, filename: string) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (selectedImage) {
            const formImgData = new FormData();
    //      formImgData.append('filename', filename);
            formImgData.append('image', selectedImage);
    //      fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/drive/image', {
    //          method: 'POST',
    //          body: formImgData,
    //      })
    //          .then((response) => console.log(response))
    //          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    };

    const handleSubmitForm = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!surveys[0]) {
            notificationHandler(
                2,
                'Não é possível submeter sem qualquer sondagem',
                notificationDispatch
            );
        }

        const lat = surveys[0].lat;
        const lng = surveys[surveys.length - 1].lng;

        const { adress, placeId } = await formSubmitGeoCoder(Number(lat), Number(lng), notificationDispatch);

        if(email) {
            if (selectedFile) {
                const fileName = selectedFile.name;
                const editedName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length - 4);
                if (selectedImage) {
                //    const oldImgName = selectedImage.name;
                //    const imgExtension = oldImgName.substring(oldImgName.length - 4, oldImgName.length);
                //    const imgName = `logo_${editedName}${imgExtension}`;
                    formData = { adress, placeId, lat, lng, email, surveys, fileName, selectedImage };
                } else {
                    formData = { adress, placeId, lat, lng, email, surveys, fileName };
                }
                const requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(formData)
                };
                const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/report', requestOptions);
                if (response.ok) {
                    handleOpenThankYou();
                    setSurveys([]);
                    resetCount();
                    handleUploadPDF(e, selectedFile.name);
                    if (selectedImage) {
                    //    const oldImgName = selectedImage.name;
                    //    const imgExtension = oldImgName.substring(oldImgName.length - 4, oldImgName.length);
                    //    const imgName = `logo_${editedName}${imgExtension}`;
                       handleUploadImage(e, selectedImage);
                    };
                }
                if (!response.ok) {
                    notificationHandler(
                        2,
                        'Erro',
                        notificationDispatch
                    );
                }

            } else {
                notificationHandler(
                    2,
                    'Para validação do relatório iremos necessitar do mesmo em formato PDF',
                    notificationDispatch
                );
            }
        } else {
            notificationHandler(
                2,
                'Insira um e-mail para poder submeter os dados',
                notificationDispatch
            ); 
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className='flex flex-col w-full h-full'>
                <Navbar setPointDataArray={setPointDataArray} setDistanceBetween={setDistanceBetween} />
                {showSliderForms ? (
                    <>
                        <div className='z-30'>
                            <div className='bg-white sm:absolute sm:right-0 h-auto max-h-full sm:h-full sm:w-[40%] overflow-y-scroll'>
                                {showThankYouForms ? (
                                    <>
                                        <ThankYou />
                                        <div className='justify-center mb-5 items-center flex space-x-2'>
                                            <button
                                                className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                onClick={handleSubmitNew}
                                            >
                                                Submeter novo estudo
                                            </button>
                                            <button
                                                className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                onClick={handleExit}
                                            >
                                                Sair
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                ) : (
                                    <>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border ml-4 mt-4'
                                            onClick={handleOpenSlider}
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                                value={{
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    className: 'h-6 sm:h-9 w-6 sm:w-9',
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <AiOutlineRight />
                                            </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                        <form className='h-auto'>
                                            {showFileSubmit ? (
                                                <>
                                                    <FileSubmit setEmail={setEmail} surveys={surveys} handleFileInput={handleFileInput} selectedFile={selectedFile} selectedImage={setSelectedImage} />
                                                    <div className='justify-center mb-5 items-center flex space-x-2'>
                                                        <button
                                                            className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                            onClick={() => {
                                                                handleOpenFileSubmit();
                                                            }}
                                                        >
                                                            Passo Anterior
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button
                                                            className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                            onClick={(event) => {
                                                                handleSubmitForm(event);
                                                            }}
                                                        >
                                                            Enviar
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </>
                                            ) : (
                                                <>
                                                    <Form handleOpenFileSubmit={handleOpenFileSubmit} handleAddSurvey={handleAddSurvey} handleClearSurveys={handleClearSurveys} surveyNumber={surveyNumber} />
                                                </>
                                            )}
                                        </form>
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {pointDataArray ? (
                            <>
                                <div className='z-30'>
                                    <div className='bg-transparent right-[35%] absolute top-auto mt-3 h-auto max-h-full w-auto'>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border'
                                            onClick={handleOpenSlider}
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                                value={{
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    className: 'h-6 sm:h-9 w-6 sm:w-9',
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <AiOutlineLeft />
                                            </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ) : (
                            <>
                                <div className='z-30'>
                                    <div className='bg-transparent absolute right-4 top-auto mt-3 mr-12 h-auto max-h-full w-auto'>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border mr-2 align-top'
                                            title='Recarregar pontos de sondagem'
                                            onClick={reload}
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                            value={{
                                            color: '#000000',
                                            className: 'h-8 sm:h-10 w-8 sm:w-10',
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <AiOutlineReload />
                                    </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border'
                                            onClick={handleOpenSlider}
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                                value={{
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    className: 'h-12 sm:h-14 w-12 sm:w-14',
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <AiOutlineLeft />
                                            </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </>
                )}
                {pointDataArray ? (
                    <>
                        <div className='z-30'>
                            <div className='bg-white absolute sm:right-0 h-auto max-h-full sm:h-full sm:w-1/3 overflow-y-scroll'>
                                <PointData pointDataArray={pointDataArray} distance={distanceBetween} handleClosePointData={handleClosePointData} map={map} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                ) : (null)}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

function reload() {
    window.location.reload();
}

function addMarkers(
    map: google.maps.Map | undefined,
    reports: GeoReport[],
    thisMarkers: google.maps.Marker[],
    setThisMarkers: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<google.maps.Marker[]>>,
    setPointDataArray: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GeoReport | null>>,
) {

    //const reports2 = [
    //    {'lat':38.991846220258516,'lng':-8.962928379927412},
    //    {'lat':39.60136813907799, 'lng':-8.409397870167226},
    //    {'lat':39.60136813907797, 'lng':-8.409397870167224},
    //    {'lat':38.75296747910795, 'lng':-9.106130361105693},
    //    {'lat':38.637778, 'lng':-8.956944},
    //    {'lat':41.216111, 'lng':-8.677222},
    //    {'lat':40.915731, 'lng':-7.276742},
    //    {'lat':38.90057404501688, 'lng':-7.094068507607758}
    //];
    //console.log(reports);
    let isVisited = false;

    const markers = reports.map((report) => {
        console.log(report.lat);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(report.lat,report.lng),
            //{ lat: report.lat, lng: report.lng },
            map: map,
            optimized: true,
            //icon: Icon
        });

        marker.addListener('click', () => {
            isVisited = !isVisited;
            if (isVisited === true) {
                setPointDataArray(report);
            }
        });

        thisMarkers.push(marker);
        setThisMarkers([...thisMarkers]);

        new MarkerClusterer({
            markers: thisMarkers,
            map,
            algorithm: new SuperClusterAlgorithm({ radius: 200 }),
        });

        return marker;
    });

    //console.log(markers);

}

const addCircles = (
    map: google.maps.Map | undefined,
    setPointDataArray: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GeoReport | null>>,
    reports: GeoReport[], circles: google.maps.Circle[],
    setCircles: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<google.maps.Circle[]>>,
) => {

    let isVisited = false;
    const addresses: string[] = [];

    reports.map((report: GeoReport) => {

        report.surveys.map(survey => {
            survey.table.map(data => {
                addresses.push(data.soilType);
            });
        });

        let color = '#FFFFFFF';
        const soilType = findMode(addresses);
        if (soilType) {
            color = getSoilTypeColor(soilType);
        }
        const marker = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: { lat: report.lat, lng: report.lng },
            radius: 500,
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map,
        });

        marker.addListener('click', () => {
            isVisited = !isVisited;
            if (isVisited === true) {
                setPointDataArray(report);
            }
        });

        circles.push(marker);
        setCircles([...circles]);
        return marker;
    });
};

export default TestMap;
```

GeoReportContext.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { geoReportDispatch, geoReportState } from '../types/ContextTypes';
import { GeoReport } from '../types/GeoReportTypes';

const initialState: geoReportState = {
    map: {},
    length: 0,
    styles: [],
};

const GeoReportContext = createContext<geoReportState | undefined>(undefined);
const GeoReportDispatchContext = createContext<geoReportDispatch | undefined>(undefined);

export const useGeoReportState = () => {
    const state = useContext(GeoReportContext);
    if (!state) {
        throw new Error('GeoReportContext must be used within a provider.');
    }
    return state;
};

export const useGeoReportDispatch = () => {
    const dispatch = useContext(GeoReportDispatchContext);
    if (!dispatch) {
        throw new Error('GeoReportDispatchContext must be used within a provider.');
    }
    return dispatch;
};

export const GeoReportProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const dispatch = {
        setMap: (map: { [key: string]: GeoReport[] }) => setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, map })),
        setLength: (length: number) => setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, length})),
        setStyles: (styles: string[]) => setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, styles})),
    };

    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<Array<GeoReport>>([]);
    const copyOfMarkers = markers;
    const fetchReports = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/report', { method: 'GET', cache: 'no-cache' })
            .then((response) => response.json());
            response.forEach((report: GeoReport) => {
            copyOfMarkers.push({
                id: report.id,
                lat: report.lat,
                lng: report.lng,
                adress: report.adress,
                placeId: report.placeId,
                surveys: report.surveys,
                fileName: report.fileName,
                imgName: report.imgName
            });
        });
    
        //const json = await response.json();
        //const copyOfMarkers = markers;
        //json.forEach((report: GeoReport) => {
        //  copyOfMarkers.push({
        //      id: report.id,
        //      lat: report.lat,
        //      lng: report.lng,
        //      adress: report.adress,
        //      placeId: report.placeId,
        //      surveys: report.surveys,
        //      fileName: report.fileName,
        //      imgName: report.imgName
        //  });
        //});

        setMarkers([...copyOfMarkers]);

        //const newMarkers = json.map((report: GeoReport) => ({
        //    id: report.id,
        //    lat: report.lat,
        //    lng: report.lng,
        //    adress: report.adress,
        //    placeId: report.placeId,
        //    surveys: report.surveys,
        //    fileName: report.fileName,
        //    imgName: report.imgName
        //})
        //);
        //console.log(newMarkers);

        //setMarkers(newMarkers);
        //console.log('2', markers);

        await dispatch.setMap(
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
            markers.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => {
                (acc[curr.adress] = acc[curr.adress] || []).push(curr);
                return acc;
            }, {} as { [key: string]: GeoReport[] }),
        );
        
        //console.log('markers', markers);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
         fetchReports();
         console.log('useGeoReportState', state);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useGeoReportState', state);
        console.log('markers', markers);
   }, []);
        
  
    return (
        <GeoReportContext.Provider value={state}>
            <GeoReportDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {children}
            </GeoReportDispatchContext.Provider>
        </GeoReportContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

[Codesandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vpwyk2?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q40006356hukjaqwq3%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q30002356hhcsuxg0e%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q30003356hcd3h00kt%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q30005356hwp337zzz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqgls3q30002356hhcsuxg0e%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q30002356hhcsuxg0e%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqglys1c00zd356hd2nxvha4%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q20001356hxk7a8q8i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqglys1c00zd356hd2nxvha4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqgls3q30005356hwp337zzz%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q30005356hwp337zzz%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqgm0xnl018b356hjfc968da%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgluc0c0064356hzbw52o8h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522SETUP_TASKS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgm0xnl018b356hjfc968da%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqgls3q30003356hcd3h00kt%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgls3q30003356hcd3h00kt%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqglubu6004i356h61usyf14%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqglubu6004i356h61usyf14%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqglvo3v00io356hc6bg8mzm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clqglvnm6002ndlil15sk1mi9%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Can someone please help me regarding this issue? Thanks in advance

[image: Console comparison for working markers vs missing markers]

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of posting almost 800 lines of code.

Comment: @Reyno I've added a link

Comment: If the object gets populated sometimes, it must be something related to its preconditions being violated, or API related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TestMap.tsx`, Add `geoReportState` as a useEffect(line: 86) dependency. As it is used by `addMarkers` and `addCircles` functions.
Also the codesandbox you added is private.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your comments, although correct, do not solve the issue, post them as comments,  not as an answer.

Comment: Sorry. Will take care.

Comment: Thank you @nisargrbhatt! That solved the issue and put an end to long days of frustration!